# What is the difference between yarn, grunt, npm, bower and nuget package manager?

Tags: .net, npm, nuget, yarnpkg

I'm a .net developer with exposure to nuget package manager console only. I was reading about nodejs and reactjs; where both require npm & yarn packet managers.

Can any one explain the difference between these products? And why are they introduced?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**npm** is the Node Package Manager.
Basically it is used to install dependencies.
In your case you will need this for React.

**Yarn package manager** is also used for to install dependencies i.e to install Javascript packages.

The difference between npm and yarn is:

##### Yarn

Takes 10-12sec to install packages.

Yarn installs all dependencies parallel.

Does not always require an internet connection to install dependencies.

##### NPM

Takes 20-25sec to install packages.

NPM always installs each dependency one after the other which may end up taking a lot of time.

Installing dependencies always requires an internet connection.

Answer (score 29):

From Wikipedia: A [package manager](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Package_manager) [...] is a collection of software tools that automates the process of installing, upgrading, configuring, and removing computer programs.

Instead of a complete computer program, you could also think of smaller parts like libraries, frameworks or just some a bunch of files packaged together.

While [NuGet](https://www.nuget.org/) focusses mainly on .NET (there are a lot of non-.NET packages on NuGet however), NPM (Node Package Manager), Yarn and Bower are JavaScript package managers.

[Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/en/) was created by Facebook and Open Sourced. Speed comparisons found online show that Yarn is faster than NPM. Yarn is also able to install packages from a cache and does not require a connection to the Internet (only if a package was downloaded before).

[Grunt](https://gruntjs.com/) is a JavaScript Task Runner, not a package manager. You can use it to automate repetitive tasks like minification, compilation, unit testing, linting, etc.